# Get byte array data from openj9 heap hump

Tags: java, heap-dump, openj9

I acquired a heap dump from a OpenJ9 java application using the command

```sh
jcmd <pid> GC.heap_dump
```

Then I open it on Eclipse Memory Analyzer to check a specific class, but when I tried to see the content of a byte array attribute of this class all the bytes appear as zero.

[image]

I tried looking to other byte array references, but all of them are the same.

Is there a way to see it content with the file that I have or I need to generate the heap dump in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a heap dump, all primitive-type fields are cleared intentionally so customers are not sending sensitive data to service providers for analysis.

If you want to examine such data yourself, use `jcmd Dump.system` together with the extension to Eclipse Memory Analyzer for reading system dumps. You can find instructions for adding that extension at https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/dump_systemdump/.

Comment: Do I need to pass any parameter to VM to get the dump in that way? I tried `jcmd 1 GC.heap_dump Dump.system` but the result was de same; tried run the JVM with the flag -Xdump it didn't work either

Comment: Now I found the way `jcmd 1 Dump.system teste.system`. Thank you very much. (I found more examples here https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/tool_jcmd)

Comment: Including the character data of strings? That would reduce the usefulness of a heap dump dramatically.

Comment: Did you succeed getting data? I am hitting the same problem.